# VBA and Graphic - Serie visible or not

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox, charts

in my Chart 1, I'd like - through a CheckBox - to show/hide a series in a graph.
However, the below code gives an error application-defined or method-defined.
Could somebody help me on fixing it?
THanks

```
If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
Worksheets("Graph").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.FullSeriesCollection.Item(1).IsFiltered = False
```

Comment: Are you planning to have a checkbox for each series? Maybe hide the range of cells corresponding to the series instead of trying to manipulate chart objects? it might be useful to see sample data and expected result

Comment: I'm curious: why not use the built-in filter?

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me:

```
Sub showhide()
    Dim cht As Chart, n As Long
    Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart
    For n = 1 To 5
        cht.FullSeriesCollection(n).IsFiltered = _
                 Not Me.OLEObjects("Checkbox" & n).Object.Value
    Next n
End Sub
```

Active sheet has a scatter plot with 5 series, and 5 ActiveX checkboxes named "Checkbox1" through "Checkbox5"

Comment: If this answered your question, please flag as "Accepted".  If not, please give some feedback so we can try to adjust accordingly.